# What is the importance of Cartan decomposition of a semi-simple Lie algebra?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I just started learning about Cartan decomposition of semi-simple Lie algebras, and I'm curious to know what are their applications in studying semi-simple Lie algebras. My guess was that it might be helpful in their classification, but when I browsed a lecture notes on classification of semi-simple lie algebra, I didn't find any part which speak about Cartan decomposition, so I'm wondering why is it important to study Cartan decomposition of a semi-simple Lie algebra ?

Note : I have posted this question on Math Stack Exchange, but have not got any reply. The link is here

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4470952/what-is-the-importance-of-cartan-decomposition-of-a-semi-simple-lie-algebra

Comment: Certainly the existence of a Cartan subalgebra is used in the usual proof of the classification of simple Lie algebras. I'm not sure if the whole Cartan decomposition is necessary for that; but it is useful for classification the representations at least.

Comment: (In fact, IIRC the existence of a Cartan subalgebra is the one small fact that Killing did not fully prove in his original proof of the classification of simple Lie algebras, although the proof is not difficult.)

Comment: Maybe because, using a Cartan decomposition of the Lie algebra of a real semisimple Lie group, we obtain a Cartan decomposition of the group,

Comment: which shows that the group is homotopy equivalent to a maximal compact subgroup.

Comment: Just so people who arrive here know about it, I've posted an answer over on the stack exchange post.